# Is it possible to solve this congruence $584= 0 \bmod x^2$ with $x$ positive integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, quadratics, congruences

> **Question**
>   Is it possible to solve the following congruence $584= 0\bmod x^2$  which is meant $x^2 \mid 584$ ?

**Note**: I don't know any method or any basic help me to solve this kind of equation

Comment: possible duplicate to :https://math.stackexchange.com/q/786718/457857

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the prime factorization of $584$ is
$$584=2^3\times 73$$
Hence, $2^2=4$ is the only perfect square (other than the trivial case of $x=1$) which divides $584$.

Comment: ok, thanks then it must doing the prime factorisation , by the way i meant is there for example any know method as CRT can solve the titled equation ?

Comment: @JęSūîsMāhbøúlã theorems such as CRT are not really necessary. This question is equivalent to solving for all $x\in\Bbb N$ such that $x^2\mid 584$, as you have written in your question. Hence, you must find all factors of $584$ which are perfect squares. Getting the prime factorization of $584$ is a good way to do this, since it lays out the factors of $584$ nicely.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

first thing to do is

$$584=1^2.2^2.2.73$$